# How can I get this style effectv with css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, styles

The images in this website are layed out fantastically: http://veerle.duoh.com/inspiration

I studied the code and I get that each that each box is positioned absolute and and then margin top and left are adjusted. However, I don't think that is done manually.

Do you know how to get that effect with css or js?

Thanks

Comment: Check this plugin: [jQuery Masonri](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses a jQuery plugin called Masonry ... very good plugin indeed ...

Here is the link to the page -> http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: ha ha that is fantastic. One of topic question:this is the first time that I ask these kind of question. Where I ask whether you know ... about other peoples work. am I wrong in doing so or am I within the norm - thanks

Comment: I don't see it as a problem - i do it all the time - look at how people do things - taking commercial code - thats a different matter but this is not ...

Answer (score 0):

The website uses the plugin [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/);

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
```

Give it a try ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a plugin called "masonry"

http://masonry.desandro.com/

the link above explains it all